# Let us know why you need access to this site

Tags: office-365

SharePoint 2013
Office 365
Access over the internet with user name and password

I am site owner and I have no issues with permissions with my own log in.

However if I grant the same permissions that I have to another user (who is a fully licensed Office 365 user) they cannot get into the Team Site. Each time they try, they are prompted to make a request "Let us know why you need access to this site." and if they complete the form, I receive the request and confirm it.....but they still don't have access.

Previously this user did have access but after experimenting with site permissions they no longer have this.

Do you have any suggestions? If not, I think the next step would be to remove this user and try recreate?

Comment: do they have read access at the site collection level rather than site?

Comment: ...deleting and restoring the user (which hopefully hasn't affected their O365 license!) had no effect. Yet, adding a completely new user works fine. Even adding an external user works fine too! #stumped

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just noticed your reply ali Sharepoint....they were given full control at site collection level and the site level.

Comment: when you say new user, do you mean a new user on sharepoint or a user from active directory?

Comment: Hi ali Sharepoint, access is being granted for connection over the internet - AD is not involved. i.e. new user in SharePoint

Comment: have you tried giving access when the user requests access? http://www.wictorwilen.se/sharepoint-2013-a-look-at-requesting-site-access also what did you do when you say experimenting with site permissions? is this on a sub site? if so check to make sure your inheriting permissions from site collection!

Comment: Hi a-S, yep, have responded to user requests and I'm try to give full control to the other use to the site collection. Permissions in the sub-site are inherited, but there is some variation there as a result of experimenting there. As I say, I've repeated the granting of access to another user and it works fine - it just seems to be this user that has got the problem. It has to be something obvious and I'm just not seeing it. I will look at it in detail again and report with further information. In the meantime, thanks for the pointers thus far ali Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

This occurs if the user has already made a request and the original is still in the queue.